# Google Cloud Project charges for download

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am getting charged for service cloud-storage/BandwidthDownloadAmerica as mentioned here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-pricing

Though, my google cloud storage bucket location, big-query dataset location and the machine where I am downloading are same as 'EU'. As per my opinion, the download from storage to machine should be considered as Ingress.

My process includes:
1. Exporting from big-query dataset to cloud storage bucket.
2. Composing the file pieces to single file.
3. Downloading the composed file.

I believe the charge mentioned in billing under:

> com.google.cloud/services/cloud-storage/BandwidthDownloadAmerica          Download
>   US EMEA

is for the step no. 3

Is there some setting that might have missed.

My project configuration is set to [default].

Any guidance is welcome. As we are new to the Google Cloud system.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

EMEA stands for "Europe, Middle East, and Africa", so BandwidthDownloadAmerica does indeed include EU. So it seems correct that you incur these charges.

(Granted, the naming is not great here, we're working to fix that)

Comment: But the confusion for us is, all the locations (bq dataset, gs buckets and server location) are set to or in EU (project is set to default).
So we were of the opinion that our download will fall in the category of Ingress and not between regions. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Ingress is upload traffic, i.e. bytes coming *into* GCS. Egress on the other hand applies if you're reading data back out of GCS.